# Swagger for Azure Service Fabric Stateless Web API application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am developing Web API service and hosting on Azure Service Fabric as Micro Service. I need to implement Swagger for the API definition and I could see SwaggerConfig.Register() method not calling while application is starting. So I could not access http://faricurl:8000/swagger.

So can you please point out how to integrate Swagger definition for Web API application.

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Comment: Are you using the Swashbuckle.Core NuGet package and implemented it as stated here for self hosted scenarios https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#self-hosted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in my comment install the core Swashbuckle NuGet package

```
install-package Swashbuckle.Core
```

Then in the Startup.cs of your WebApi project add

```
 config.EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
        .EnableSwaggerUi();
```