# Enabling security for Swagger UI on Service Fabric Web API Services

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, swagger-ui

We enabled Swagger on Azure Service Fabric application using below link. 
[Swagger for Azure Service Fabric Stateless Web API application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088573/swagger-for-azure-service-fabric-stateless-web-api-application)

But, we are unable to secure the swagger UI using OAuth (Azure AAD application). Can anyone please provide some guidance on enabling security on Swagger UI for the application hosted on Service Fabric.

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any real difference to how a Service Fabric hosted Web Api would handle this compare to a "normal" App Service or IIS hosted Web Api.

The following article does a good job of describing how to secure a Swagger UI using OAuth2 and IdentityServer3: 
http://knowyourtoolset.com/2015/09/secure-web-apis-with-swagger-swashbuckle-and-oauth2-part-4/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I followed the document and referred few others. I could see the "Available authorizations" popup windows comes and the authentication goes successfully with AAD. But after authentication, I could not see the browser opened for authentication closes and the token comes back with the swagger.


I see the below url in the browser tab which opoend for authentication, then no token comes back to swagger -


[https ://localhost:444/swagger/ui/o2c-html#access_token=<actual token>&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&state=oauth2&session_state=<guid>]